# Azure cosmosDB gremlin - how to update vertex property with another vertex's property

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

On an Azure cosmosDB gremlin instance,

I have 2 vertices A and B linked by and edge E.
Both vertices has a 'name' property.

I'd like to run a query which will take A's name and put it in B

when I run

```
g.V("AId").as("a").oute().inv().hasLabel('B').property("name",select('a').values('name'))
```

I get the following error :

GraphRuntimeException ExceptionMessage : Gremlin Query Execution Error: Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type GraphTraversal.

It looks like the select operator is not correctly used.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

*EDITED based on discussion in comments*

You have `oute` and `inv` in lower case. In general, the steps use `camelCase` naming, such as `outE` and  `inV` (outside of specific GLVs), but in the comments it was mentioned that CosmosDB will accept all lower case step names. Assuming therefore, that is not the issue here, the query as written looks fine in terms of generic Gremlin. The example below was run using TinkerGraph, and uses the same `select` mechanism to pick the property value.

```java
gremlin> g.V(3).as("a").outE().inV().has('code','LHR').property("name",select('a').values('city')) 
==>v[49]

gremlin> g.V(49).values('name')
==>Austin
```

What you are observing may be specific to CosmosDB and it's probably worth contacting their support folks to double check.

Comment: The interpreter within Azure cosmos is not case sensitive, you can write both inv and inV

Comment: OK then, unfortunately it looks like you have encountered a limitation with the CosmosDB Gremlin support, as other than the casing point, the query is fine and works on TinkerGraph.

Comment: One other thought, it looks as if the query engine is perhaps not actually executing the `select` anonymous traversal. I'm not too hopeful but you could try changing it to `__.select(...)` or even adding a `.next()` after the select. Neither should be needed in Gremlin, but I'm not sure what the restrictions might be with the implementation you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed it's a bit weird because the select operator returns the correct vertex when I write the following query : ```g.V("AId").as("a").oute().inv().hasLabel('B').select('a')```
I'll try to ask directly to the support, thanks again